# Unirest gives NoSuchMethodError when using asString method

Tags: java, unirest

I am trying to do a simple get to an endpoint and get the response body as and HttpResponse using the asString() method. The code compiles, but bugs out at runtime saying there is no such method error.

I imported Unirest into my maven build and I have been following the documentation [here](http://kong.github.io/unirest-java/#requests)

```
HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.get("http://mywebsite/post")
                  .basicAuth("myapiuser", "mypassword")
                  .asString();
```

And this is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig$Builder.setNormalizeUri(Z)Lorg/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig$Builder;
    at kong.unirest.apache.DefaultFactory.tryNormalize(DefaultFactory.java:47)
    at kong.unirest.apache.DefaultFactory.apply(DefaultFactory.java:42)
    at kong.unirest.apache.DefaultFactory.apply(DefaultFactory.java:32)
    at kong.unirest.apache.RequestPrep.getHttpRequestBase(RequestPrep.java:88)
    at kong.unirest.apache.RequestPrep.prepare(RequestPrep.java:69)
    at kong.unirest.apache.ApacheClient.request(ApacheClient.java:122)
    at kong.unirest.BaseRequest.asString(BaseRequest.java:177)
    at com.ideiio.testdataloader.TestDataLoader.testRestGet(TestDataLoader.java:62)
    at com.ideiio.testdataloader.TestDataLoader.main(TestDataLoader.java:34)
```

I can't determine if this is just an issue with missing dependencies on my part (I am quite new to maven) or if it is an issue with the code itself (although, the Unirest call is almost an exact copy from the docs).

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.ideiio.testdataloader</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestDataLoader</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>TestDataLoader</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
      <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.konghq</groupId>
      <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.11</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: Will be good to see your pom.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a dependences issue, I fixed it adding a newer version of httpclient in pom. 4.5.9 which overides the 4.5.6.

```
<dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.9</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at you exception it is looking for method "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig$Builder.setNormalizeUri(Z)Lorg/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig$Builder" where as i can see the method signature as 
 "public RequestConfig.Builder setNormalizeUri(boolean normalizeUri)
" 
Here problem could be related to the version of incompatible dependencies used or may be due to the conflict because of other jars in your class path. Can please share your pom.xml.